# Empty $_FILES array for Dropzone submit

Tags: cakephp, dropzone.js

I have a `Products` controller with a `view` function and a `processImages` function.

The $_FILES variable received by the `processImages` function is always empty and I can't figure out why!

**PS**: The '1' passed at the end of the `processImages` function is the Product ID, so I can create the relationships after the file is uploaded.

My `view.ctp` view is:

```
<form action="/project002/products/processImages/1" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
  <input  class="btn btn-primary" id="processImageUploads" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

---

```
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
        paramName: "productImage",
        maxFiles: <?php echo 16 - count($product['Image']);?>,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.jpeg,.png',
        dictInvalidFileType: 'This file type is not supported.',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        dictRemoveFile: 'Remove Image',
        parallelUploads: 16,
        uploadMultiple: true,

        init: function() {
            this.on("addedfile", function() {
                if (this.files[<?php echo 15 - count($product['Image']);?>]!=null){
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                    $( "#count_left" ).html('Image upload limit reached!');
                }
            });

            var myDropzone = this;

            $("#processImageUploads").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                // If the user has selected at least one file, AJAX them over.
                if (myDropzone.files.length !== 0) {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    $('#my-awesome-dropzone').submit();
                } else {
                    $('#my-awesome-dropzone').submit();
                }
            });
            myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
                myDropzone.removeFile(file);
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about, the AJAX call, or the normal form submit. In any case, submitting the form immediately after the AJAX process has been triggered is a pretty bad idea, and will most probably leave you with two non-working requests, one that is aborted prematurely, and one that doesn't contain any file data.

Comment: I think you've pointed out exactly my problem about the two incomplete requests. Is it possible to disable the AJAX call and do it via a normal submit? I'm not really familiar with AJAX so would avoid it for the time being if possible.

Comment: I don't think so, file input elements cannot be populated dynamically, they are read-only for historical security reasons.